# Filter positions in a list, Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to print the elements of odd index. Currently is printing index.

I don't understand how I can print elements of this index?

```
f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f lst = filter odd [0..length lst]

-- I can't edit this part
main = do
   inputdata <- getContents
   mapM_ (putStrLn. show). f. map read. lines $ inputdata
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to do this "on foot":

```
odds [] = []
odds [x] = []
odds (e1:e2:xs) = e2 : odds xs
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `zip` to turn your `[Int]` into an `[(Int, Int)]`, where the first element is the index and the second is the original value. Then you can use `fst` and `snd` to get the results you want:

```
f :: [a] -> [a]
f lst = map fst $ filter (odd.snd) indexed where
    indexed = zip lst [0..]
```

Note that there is no need to restrict this to a list of `Int`s, it will now work on a list of any type:

```
> f "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
"wryipsfhkzcbm"
```

Comment: yep, but `lst [0..]`. Thanks so much, Vic!

Answer (score 8):

```
Prelude> map snd $ filter (odd . fst) (zip [0 .. ] ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"])
["bb","dd"]
```

Comment: This shows you get the point-free version by zipping index first:  `f = map snd . filter (odd . fst) . zip [0..]`

Answer (score 5):

I think the shortest one is with list comprehensions.

```
Prelude> let arr = [0..10]
Prelude> [j | (i, j) <- zip [0..] arr, odd i]
[1,3,5,7,9]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f lst = [lst!!i|i<-[1..length lst],odd  i]
```

Comment: This is terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more implementations of f which I find rather elegant are:

```
f lst = map (lst!!) [1, 3..(length lst)]
```

and

```
import Data.List.Split

f lst = concatMap (drop 1) (chunksOf 2 lst)
```

Comment: The first one is horribly slow.