# Haskell filter by list index

Tags: haskell

I have function:

```
isEven n = (mod n 2) == 0
```

And a I want only even numbers, I get:

```
filter isEven [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6] -- -> 2, 4, 6
```

So far so  good.

My question is: Is there in the function where I can filter by list index? (you can imagine js filter where second parameter is the index).

If not is there any reason why this is not included and how can I do it in a good haskell way?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399696/filter-positions-in-a-list-haskell

Comment: Yes thanks, i will use zip. But it doesn say why is the reason why it is not included in the filter function directly

Comment: @UtkarshDubey the reason is that a linked list is not an array. On a list, it's generally not performant to work with indices so it's discouraged.

Comment: @user2693928, hope you will find this useful and it will answer your query: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ilist/docs/Data-List-Index.html

Comment: @user2693928: I think because in functional programming such list is seen as a sequence of items, and the *index* exists, but is not commonly used. Especially since an index lookup `list !! k` happens in *O(n)*. When using lists, it is rather uncommon to take the index into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a function that filters on both values and indexes, you can write it yourself like this:

```
filterIndexed :: (a -> Int -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterIndexed p xs = [x|(x,i) <- zip xs [0..], p x i]
```

It uses a list comprehension which is nice for this kind of thing (filter and project). The reason this is not in the standard libraries is because it is a relatively rare operation, and it's fairly easy to have the list comprehension directly in your code.

Comment: Thanks, understood. Indexes are not common used and if you want you can pass zip and have access to the indexes.

Comment: Alternatively: `filterIndex f = map snd . filter (f . fst) . enumerate` given `enumerate = zip [0..]` (which should really be in a library somewhere, if it isn’t already)—also assuming only the index is needed, although it’s easy to adjust if not: just use `uncurry f` instead of `f . fst`.